# I am getting timeout error after loading table data using Power Query Editor. How can I proceed further?

Tags: powerbi, data-visualization, editor, loading, business-intelligence

I am getting the below error while selecting the **"close and apply"** option in Power Query Editor:-

`We timed out waiting for page 'https://www.imf.org/en/Publications/WEO/weo-database/2020/April/weo-report?c=512,914,612,614,311,213,911,314,193,122,912,313,419,513,316,913,124,339,638,514,218,963,616,223,516,918,748,618,624,522,622,156,626,628,228,924,233,632,636,634,238,662,960,423,935,128,611,321,243,248,469,253,642,643,939,734,644,819,172,132,646,648,915,134,652,174,328,258,656,654,336,263,268,532,944,176,534,536,429,433,178,436,136,343,158,439,916,664,826,542,967,443,917,544,941,446,666,668,672,946,137,546,674,676,548,556,678,181,867,682,684,273,868,921,948,943,686,688,518,728,836,558,138,196,278,692,694,962,142,449,564,565,283,853,288,293,566,964,182,359,453,968,922,714,862,135,716,456,722,942,718,724,576,936,961,813,726,199,733,184,524,361,362,364,732,366,144,146,463,528,923,738,578,537,742,866,369,744,186,925,869,746,926,466,112,111,298,927,846,299,582,474,754,698,&s=PPPGDP,&sy=2014&ey=2021&ssm=0&scsm=1&scc=0&ssd=1&ssc=0&sic=0&sort=country&ds=.&br=1'.`

I modified the code in **"Advanced Editor"** tab by adding timeout argument as: `Web.BrowserContents("https://microsoft.com", [WaitFor = [Timeout = #duration(0,0,10,0)]])`

But still, I am unable to load the table data.
Please help to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

Try Increasing the Timeout parameter from 10 to more.
Like Web.BrowserContents("https://microsoft.com", [WaitFor = [Timeout = #duration(0,0,**30**,0)]])